# Proving a Sequence of Distributions Converges to the Atomic Distribution $\delta_0$

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $g_n$ be a sequence of random variables such that the sequence of distributions $\mu_{g_n}$ converges to a distribution $\nu$. Let $\alpha_n$ be a sequence of positive numbers that converges to $0$. Prove that the sequence $\mu_{\alpha_n g_n}$ converges to the atomic distribution $\delta_0$ which is given by : $\delta_0 (B) = 1$ if $0 \in B$ and $0$ otherwise.

Ideas:

I know a theorem that states if $g_n \to g$ in measure $\mu$, then $\mu_{g_n} \to \mu_g$.

Since $\mu_0 =\delta_0$, I need to show that $\alpha_n g_n \to 0$ in measure $\mu$. Is this the correct approach?

In order to prove this, I have to show that $$\mu ( \{ \omega: | \alpha_n g_n (\omega) | \ge \delta \}) \to 0$$ as $n \to \infty$.

Since $\alpha_n$ is defined to be positive, we require $|g_n| \ge \frac{\delta}{\alpha_n}$ which should increase boundlessly as $n \to \infty$.

Is there some concrete way of proving/showing this? Am I even on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [Skotohod's representation therorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skorokhod%27s_representation_theorem), which ensures that there exists a sequence of random variables $\{X_n\}$ with marginal distributions $\mu_{g_n}$ and a random variable $X$, whose distribution is $\nu$, defined on the same probability space such that $X_n\to X$ a.s. Now, wp1,
$$
a_n X_n=a_n(X_n-X)+a_n X\to 0,
$$
which implies that $a_n X_n\xrightarrow{d}0$.

---

Alternatively, let $F_n(x):=\mu_{g_n}((\infty,x])$ and $F(x):=\nu((\infty,x])$. Then $F_n\to F$ for all continuity points of $F$ (call this set $C_F$). Now, $\mu_{a_ng_n}((-\infty,x])=F_n(x/a_n)$. For $x>0$, $x/a_n\to \infty$, implying that for each $M\in C_F$,
$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}F_n(x/a_n)\ge \liminf_{n\to\infty}F_n(M)= F(M).
$$
Thus,
$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}F_n(x/a_n)\ge \sup_{M\in C_F}F(M)=1.
$$
Similarly, for $x<0$, $\limsup_{n\to\infty}F_n(x/a_n)= 0$. That is, $\mu_{a_ng_n}\to \delta_0$.